# ValueError when plotting pcolormesh with a defined function that has if satements within

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, plot, error-handling

Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

x    = np.linspace(1,100,100)
y    = np.linspace(500,10000,100)

x    = np.unique(x)
y    = np.unique(y)
X,Y  = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z    = myfunction(a,b,c,d,Y,e,f,g,X)

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

where a, b, c, d, e, f, and g are values that I arbitrarily set. The problem is that when I run the above code I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

because my defined function has 'if' statements within. What could I do to rectify this issue?

Comment: You should provide the body of `myfunction`, but my guess is you're probably doing something like `if array1` or `if array1 and array2`. That's why it tells you to use `a.any()` or `a.all()`, which is IMO a terrible description. Suppose you want to AND two arrays, you use the bitwise and operator, `&` instead of `and`. If you want every element of `array` to be different from 0, then try `array1.all()`.

Comment: @K.Cl , yes you are right. I am using the if statement as you have described. Could you, however, try to help me find a solution to the problem?

Comment: To help you, I need to see: 1. The full traceback and 2. the full code of `my_function` or at least the vicinity of where this error occurs.